# The Grothendieck ring of varieties with classical Zariski

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, grothendieck-rings, projective-varieties, zariski-topology

Consider $\mathcal{V}_k$, the category of $k$-varieties over the finite field $k = \mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements. We see varieties in the old "classical" sense of the word, foreseen with the old Zariski topology (pre-Grothendieck).

Now define the Grothendieck ring $A_k := K_0(\mathcal{V}_k)$ of $k$-varieties in the usual way.

- What is known about the structure of $A_k$?
- Does it carry interesting motivic information (such as its modern brother does) ?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. In particular, what is the "modern brother"?

Comment: @Sasha: the Grothendieck ring defined on the category of $k$-varieties foreseen with the modern Zariski topology.

Comment: What is the "modern Zariski topology"? And what do you mean by "foreseen"?

Comment: @Sasha: in the old Zariski, the closed sets were the algebraic subsets (of the algebraic variety), in the modern version, one works with spectra of rings of which the points are prime ideals, and closed sets are of the form $V(I) = \{ P \vert I \subseteq P \}$, where $P$ varies over prime ideals. By "foreseen with," I mean "endowed with."

Comment: With the standard definition of the Grothendieck ring there are relations $[X] = [Z] + [X \setminus Z]$ for each closed $Z \subset X$, which show that the class of $Z$ does not depend on the subscheme structure (reduced or non-reduced) you consider on it. I guess this shows that what you call "modern" and "classical" topology (I would say instead, "category of schemes" vs "category of varieties") give rise to the same Grothendieck ring.

Comment: @Sasha: now I lost you. The classical Zariski is only defined on maximal ideals, while modern Zariski is defined on all prime ideals. What is the connection with the reduced spectrum ?

Comment: The difference between maximal ideals versus prime ideals is bridged by the Nullstellensatz, which says that the topologies on $\operatorname{MaxSpec}$ and $\operatorname{Spec}$ mutually define each other. The only other difference is that varieties are typically integral, or at least reduced (and maybe separated or even quasi-projective, but that problem disappears as well if you can cut and paste).